# Shortest path distances of all node pair matlab to python equivalence

Tags: python, matlab, networkx

I'm trying to convert MATLAB to python code. I was wondering if the equivalence between these two functions were correct. I know this is for unweighted calculation, that's what I want, but where are the ***source and target nodes*** in python networkx function ?

**MATLAB**

```
d = distances(G,s,t,'Method',algorithm)
```

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html

Shortest path distances of all node pairs

**PYTHON**

```
path_lengths = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G))
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a little bit if you want answers. [`all_pairs_shortest_path_length`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length.html).
If possible you should post a MWE (minimum working example).

Comment: And  besides, I think you can easily figure this out for yourself by running the code to see if they produce similar answers. As you already have the matlab code and know the python function to use it should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Since you miss `s` and `t` in the `python` code, you probably want to have only the length of the shortest path between `s` and `t` and not solve the all pairs shortest path problem. So you want to use [`shortest_path_lengths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length). This is the distance between only this pair of nodes.

```
d = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=s, target=t)
```

However, you would still not use the `algorithm` parameter of the Matlab code. So that code will not be fully equivalent.

Comment: It gives distance for one, not for all node pairs between source and target, right ?

Comment: Yes, it's only these two nodes.

Comment: If my answer solves your issue, please accept the answer.